# Поменять цвет глаза в новом Edit для паролей на светлый

Tags: android

Я обновил как обычно `Android Support Repository` до `36.0.0` и стали доступны версии `24.2.0` для `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` и т.д.

И теперь появилась автоматическая кнопка (глаз): скрыть/показать введенный пароль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде круто и не нужно вручную это делать, но вопрос такой:

Как поменять его на белый(светлый) цвет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цвет изменяется параметром `passwordToggleTint`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/passTextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?attr/textInputLayoutStyle"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: Пример:]

Comment: Я верил! Спасибо!!!

Comment: @iFr0z Кроме того, можно поставить свой значок, вовсе не похожий на глаз, через атрибут `app:passwordToggleDrawable` (метод [`setPasswordVisibilityToggleDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setPasswordVisibilityToggleDrawable(int)))

Comment: @pavlofff ох спасибо большое за инфу!!

Comment: правда полностью меняется на определенный цвет, эффект нажатия перестал работать так сказать, но это мелочи:)

Comment: @iFr0z [Твит про этот значок глаза](https://twitter.com/crafty/status/766305675030953984), как  заменить и добавить анимацию

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо большое!:)